# Ansible aws_eip: 'unsupported parameter for module: device_id'

Tags: ansible, elastic-ip

I'm trying to assign an EIP to an ec2 instance using the guide for the [aws_eip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_eip_module.html) module. However for some reason the aws_eip module has some issue with `device_id`. I am using ansible 1.9.4:

```
TASK: [associate an elastic IP with an instance] ****************************** 
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: unsupported parameter for module: device_id

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I assume it wants me to use something other than device_id.  What should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the examples in the doc are wrong.  You should use `instance_id` instead of `device_ip`.  This is what your task should look like (note that `"{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][0]['id'] }}"` is the ansible variable that stores the instance id):

```
- name: associate an elastic IP with an instance
  ec2_eip:
    region: 'us-west-2'
    instance_id: "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][0]['id'] }}"
    ip: "{{ elastic_ip }}"
```

Comment: There is a note about version support for each module's parameter. And for `device_id` it is `version_added: "2.0"`. Consider upgrading your Ansible version.